# How to solve SP2-0027: Input is too long error for the ddl script generated using Liquibase?

Tags: sqlplus, liquibase

I am generating my `DDL` script for Oracle using `Liquibase` (using the liquibase in `offline` mode as specified [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/offline.html#:%7E:text=If%20your%20environment%20does%20not,%E2%80%9D%2C%20and%20%E2%80%9CtagExists%E2%80%9D.)). When running the generated CREATE TABLE sql through `sql plus`, I am getting the following error

> Regarding SP2-0027: Input is too long

[This](https://smarttechways.com/2017/09/06/sp2-0027-input-is-too-long-2499-characters/#:%7E:text=Error%20occurred%20due%20to%20SQL,SQL%20queries%20into%20different%20line.) explains that we have to break the single line sql to multiple lines so that we can run such long sqls through sql plus.

Is there a way to break the single line sql in `Liquibase`?

The Sql plus version is `Version 18.4.0.0.0`

> Edit : When I split the sql into two lines, it is successfully
> executing.

Comment: Can you add the line causing the issue (Is it the DDL or the DMLs for the changelog) and the version of your oracle client?

Comment: The error is upon the execution of CREATE TABLE script and the sqlplus version is added in the question.

Comment: Have you tried adding a modifySql (replace=","  with=",\r\n" for the corresponsing changeset to print out new lines (on windows) after each comma?

Comment: No. How can I do that ?